# When is ValueError triggered in django both in create and update and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, django

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Enter Company name")

class Product(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

class Inventory(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)


class InventoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InventoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['product'] = forms.ChoiceField(
                choices = self.grouped_products
            )

     def grouped_products(self):
        grouped_list = list()
        grouped_list.append(("","-- select product --"))
        for company in Company.objects.all():
            grouped_list.append(
                (
                    company.name,
                    list(
                        (p.id, p.name) for p in Product.objects.filter(company=company).order_by('name')
                    )
                )
            )

        return grouped_list

    def clean_product(self):
            product_id = self.cleaned_data['product']

            product = Product.objects.filter(pk=product_id)               
            return product
```

I updated the product field in InventoryForm so I can display a grouped selection based on company, but now when I tried to save or update inventory I get this error

> Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/catalog/inventory/7/change/
>   Exception Value: Cannot assign "'5'": "Inventory.product" must be a
>   "Product" instance.

I understand that the selected product has an id of 5 and it cannot assign that value to `Inventory.product` so I added a `def clean_product(self)` method to return the real product object based on id but it's not working.

**update 1**

```
def grouped_products(self):
        grouped_list = list()
        grouped_list.append(("","-- select product --"))
        for company in Company.objects.all():
            p = Product.objects.filter(company=company).order_by('name')
            grouped_list.append(
                (
                    company.name,
                    [p]
                )
            )

        return grouped_list
```

**error**

`Exception Type:    ValueError
Exception Value:

too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

**update 2**

```
for company in Company.objects.all():
            grouped_list.append(
                (
                    company.name,
                    list(
                        (p) for p in Product.objects.filter(company=company).order_by('name')
                    )
                )
            )

        return grouped_list
```

**error**

`'Product' object is not iterable`

**update 3**

```
for company in Company.objects.all():
            grouped_list.append(
                (
                    company.name,
                    [Product.objects.filter(company=company).order_by('name')]
                )
            )

        return grouped_list
```

**error**

`too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `grouped_product` is pointless; it is not the code causing your error. You need to change `clean_product` to return a single Product instance; do this by using `.get()` instead of `.filter()`.

Comment: can you please share code, i'm new to python and django and i'm still having this problem

Comment: Literally, replace `filter` with `get` in your `cleaned_product` method.

Comment: finally it worked!!! I was expecting to get single product instance when using .filter() since I provided pk